# angularjs $http.get filtering by category

Tags: mysql, angularjs

suppose I have some data in a MySQL database like this: http://www.ssa.gov/oact/STATS/table4c6.html

I'd like to create a page with an age slider that displays the corresponding death probability.

My first idea was to approach this problem by using MySQL queries such as:

```
GET 'death_prob' where 'age' = {slider_value} and 'gender' = 'male';
```

then trigger an ajax event to fire whenever the slider value changes which will re-query the database and display the results without any need for refreshing the page. The problem with this approach is that as the user fiddles with the slider, there could be hundreds of requests which seems less than ideal.

I read this w3schools page on Angular SQL: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_sql.asp

I'm  thinking it would be better practice to query the whole table, encode as JSON, and then access it as an Angular controller.

I've only seen examples with the ng-repeat directive which displays the entire table, but I haven't had any luck finding a directive or means of piping that lets me get a death probability based on age for example similarly to the way a MySQL query can.

is there an article on this somewhere or a jsfiddle example? Is this even conventional?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually depends on how big your data is and how frequent the user is likely to use the slider.

But the general advice it to fetch *only* the data which necessary to render the UI to the user, but if the response consists small set of data (*still arguable*) it's okay to fetch as a whole and keep it in memory.

In case, the event of making server calls are much frequent, you should be using some sort of debouncing to make it convenient for you and the user. For Eg. use model options

```
ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: { default: 300, blur: 0 } }"
```

**Edit as per OP's update**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('actuarialCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.search = {
    age: 65
  };

  function makeRequest(query) {
    return $http.get("http://www.rad-site.com/query2.php", {
      params: query ? query : null
    });
  }

  function updateScope(response) {
    $scope.ages = response.records;
  }
  makeRequest().success(updateScope);

  $scope.$watch('search.age', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    makeRequest({
      age: newVal
    }).success(updateScope);
  });

  angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    $("#slider-range-max").slider({
      range: "max",
      min: 1,
      max: 119,
      value: $scope.search.age
    }).on("slidechange", function(event, ui) {
      $scope.search.age = ui.value;
      $scope.$apply(); // make sure to call this
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
@media (max-width: 980px) {
  body {
    padding-top: 0;
  }
}
#sliderspacer {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  max-width: 600px;
}
.form-control {
  max-width: 100px;
}
#mfradio {
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.rad-site.com/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="http://www.rad-site.com/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
      <h1>Period Life Expectancy Based on Age</h1>

      <h3>Source: Social Security Agency</h3>

      <hr>
      <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="actuarialCtrl">
        <p>
          <label for="amount">Age:
            <input type="text" ng-model="search.age" id="amount" class="form-control">
          </label>
          <div id="sliderspacer">
            <div id="slider-range-max"></div>
          </div>
        </p>
        <div id="mfradio">
          <div class="radio">
            <label ng-model="male">
              <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>Male</label>
          </div>
          <div class="radio">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">Female</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <table id="searchTextResults" class="table">
          <tr ng-repeat="x in ages | filter:searchText:true">
            <td>{{ x.age }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.deathprob }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.numlives }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.lifeexp }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.gender }}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('actuarialCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.search = { age : 65 };

    function makeRequest(query) {
        return $http.get("http://www.rad-site.com/query2.php", {
            params: query ? query : null
        });
    }

    function updateScope(response) {
        $scope.ages = response.records;
    }
    makeRequest().success(updateScope);

    $scope.$watch('search.age', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        makeRequest({ age : newVal }).success(updateScope);
    });

    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        $("#slider-range-max").slider({
            range: "max",
            min: 1,
            max: 119,
            value: $scope.search.age
        }).on( "slidechange", function( event, ui ) {
            // you don't necessarily need to debounce as you have 
            // slidechange event, which will only update once the value changed
            $scope.search.age = ui.value;
            $scope.$apply(); // make sure to call this
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: interesting! Perhaps you can show me how to implement that? Here's what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/farghole22/0a0qm3zc/

unfortunately the data isn't filtered when the slider is adjusted: the user has to manually enter data into the textbox. 

Also I'm at a loss as to how to filter gender. I know I have to add a second pipe but I'm not sure how to specify male/female

Comment: @user23058230 It's been a while to look at your fiddle, check my edit. Inspect ajax requests to see the query params. Hope this helps.